# Is there a way for TeamCity to pass the last pinned build number into the current build's build step?

Tags: teamcity, continuous-integration

I'd like to be able to pass the last pinned build number to my TeamCity build step. I didn't see a system parameter that I could pass in, like I do with the current build number.

Is there a parameter for this that I didn't see? Or is there a way to get the version number from a URL? - thanks

Comment: Why do you need this pinned build number? What task are you trying to solve with it?

Comment: I'd like to be able to figure out the range of build numbers between two pinned builds so that I can automatically move the appropriate issue tracking cases into a "release to qa" state. 

In the end, I'm going to use dependent build artifacts and issue tracking state to solve my particular problem, but I'm guessing folks may still be interested in how to get pinned build information.

Comment: We upgrade a copy of our database on each build.  So in our case we'd like the last pinned build in order to determine which database to copy for the current build.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I haven't been unable to find a way to pass pinned build information into my TeamCity build step - which is really what I'd like to do.

The next best solution I can think of is to query TeamCity for pinned builds using their [REST API](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin). With the right query, the API will return an XML structure which would include the build number for each pinned build, amongst other useful information.

At it's simplest, the request would look something like this:

```
http://<buildserver>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/?locator=pinned:true
```

Answer (score -1):

TeamCity makes a bunch of variables available to you as system environment variables.

The list of variables can be found here:

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Predefined+Build+Parameters

The build number assigned by TeamCity can be found at `build.number`

--

You can also get a record of all previous builds of a project by subscribing to the RSS feed of that build in the 'My Settings and Tools' section of TeamCity.  An appropriately placed powershell script or shell script could grab this RSS and parse it.  In there, you could configuse an RSS feed that shows the recent builds of a project... It does not appear to show pinned status in the RSS, but you can see the last few builds.

--

Final idea - if you are using MySQL as your configuration database, you could write a query directly against the tables in the MySQL database.  This would allow you to query for any field on the build, ordering however you needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that is the build number I'm already passing in to my build script. I'd like to pass in the build number from the *last pinned build*.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. One idea I had was to use the permalink to the last pinned build and grab an artifact that has that build's number in it. I think this will probably work but it doesn't sound ideal...